# when to use Function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have been writing javascript for one or two months , I never used Function keyword , like Function.method(); when I define function , I simply define it as :

```
function fooBar () {};
```

Can you give me an example when using Function is more convenient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions#The_Function_constructor) constructor so often, it basically uses code evaluation to build a function.

It requires string arguments, being the last argument the function body, and the previous ones will be the arguments of the new function itself, for example:

```
var add = new Function("a", "b", "return a + b;");
add(5,5) == 10;
```

**When you should use it?**

As I said not so often, I personally try to avoid them since they use code evaluation.

A thing to note is that *no closures* are created when functions are built in this way, which can be a good thing for some performance circumstances, for example to shorten the process of identifier resolution, but you should use them with care...

Answer (score 1):

> Every function in JavaScript is
>   actually a Function object.

Read **[Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function)**

> Function objects created with the
>   Function constructor are parsed when
>   the function is created. This is less
>   efficient than declaring a function
>   and calling it within your code,
>   because functions declared with the
>   function statement are parsed with the
>   rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

function view(){
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML="New Text here";
}

this function can you call from either keyboard events of mouse events